# LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands

Tags: moderncv

I used Texlive and Texmake in Windows 7,for the following code

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{bidimoderncv}
   \cvtheme[blue]{bidicasual} % you can use orange, red, green and blue as options
  \usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
   \usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[RTLdocument]{bidi}
\def\refname{تألیفات}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=parsidigits]{XB Niloofar}
%\newfontfamily\rmfamily[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}
\resumename{رزومه}
\firstname{م}
\familyname{ی}
\title{رزومهٔ من}
%\address{تهران، خیابان آزادی پلاک ۹}
\mobile{091911111}
%\phone{۹۸-55424099}
%\fax{۹۸۹۰۸۳۴۲}
\email{h@yahoo.com
 }
\extrainfo{hv}
%\photo[84pt]{scan0001}
\quote{با عرض سلام و .}
\begin{document}
\maketitle




\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-} % change the symbol for lists

\section{روزهای پیشنهادی }
\cvlistitem{سه شنبه}
\cvlistitem{چهار شنبه}
\cvlistitem{از ساعت 8صبح الی 18 عصر}            % optional other symbol


\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}       % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\end{document}
```

I get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands
```

`\listfiles`

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex 2015.11.9)  12 NOV 2015 19:32
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**"./Suggested days.tex"
(./Suggested days.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidimoderncv.cls
Document Class: bidimoderncv 
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
Package: color 2014/10/28 v1.1a Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package color Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 142.

(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2015/03/25 v4.04 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (TeX Liv
e/RRM/JK)
))
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 94.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen102
\Gin@req@width=\dimen103
)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/marvosym/marvosym.sty
Package: marvosym 2011/07/20 v2.2 Martin Vogel's Symbols font definitions
)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty

! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \documentclass{
                   article}
The document may only declare one class.


! LaTeX Error: File `lipsum.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.2 \usepackage{lipsum}\sloppy
                              % Just for this example^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 875 strings out of 493706
 10281 string characters out of 6148913
 62623 words of memory out of 5000000
 4267 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3940 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 32i,0n,21p,298b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

So, how can I fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me with texlive 2015. Are you sure that you compile exactly this code?

Comment: Your document runs without error here

Comment: @Dear  Ulrike Fischer, Yes I sure

Comment: How to send PDF file?

Comment: add `\listfiles` to your preamble and then post the resulting log so we can compare which versions you have

Comment: @Dear David Carlisle, I send log file, thanks your time

Comment: I only see the comment if you use `@` followed by my user name not `@dear` Also you need to mark multi-line blocks using the `{}` button in the editor (see my edit) not using a backtick.

Comment: The posted log seems to show that there is  a `\documentclass` command in `c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty`  can you check that file? I suspect an accidental edit has over-written the hyperref package with a document.